# rails_admin duplicate action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I want to make custom action for rails_admin which copies whole data from some item(except id) in database into form that creates new item(rails_admin "new" action).

I want't to allow users create items with no necessity of filling all field in form.

Comment: If you want to know how custom action is create check this wiki I have added a link to it https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but this library appears to add a duplicate action to rails_admin:

https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_clone